# Enviar valor de recurso a método para reproducir Sonido en MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android

Quisiera realizar un método que pudiera recibir el audio a reproducir, 
Tengo este código:

```
soundChiste.release();
soundChiste = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.academiaguarciacivil);
soundChiste.start();
btnAcademiaPause.setEnabled(true);
btnAcademiaStop.setEnabled(true);
```

Quiero hacer una funcióon y pasarle por parámetro lo que cambiaría la siguiente linea

```
soundChiste = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.PARAMETRO
```

Que tipo de dato sería ?? un String ? Dudo en como plantearlo

EDIT: Entonces esto estaría bien ?

```
public void prueba(String archivo){
    soundChiste.release();
    soundChiste = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.archivo);
    soundChiste.start();
    btnAcademiaPause.setEnabled(true);
    btnAcademiaStop.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Y llamarlo luego:

```
prueba("cancion1");
```

Resultando después en:

```
soundChiste = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.cancion1);
```

Comment: Digamos que quiero pasar un parametro que será el nombre de un archivo sin extensión.. por ejemplo prueba. y que en el codigo que he puesto "PARAMETRO" se sustituya por prueba

Comment: Entonces como tendría que hacer lo que quiero hacer @gbianchi ?

Comment: Lo que quiero es que por medio de una funcion, en el parámetro se le pase ese nombre de archivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función debe recibir un valor tipo int ya que los recursos se almacenan en variables tipo int, este sería un ejemplo

```
public void cambiaSonido(int idSonido){

  soundChiste.release();
  soundChiste = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), idSonido);
  soundChiste.start();
  btnAcademiaPause.setEnabled(true);
  btnAcademiaStop.setEnabled(true);

}
```

para llamar el método simplemente envía como parámetro el id del recurso, ejemplos:

```
cambiaSonido(R.raw.academiaguarciacivil);
```

---

Todos los recursos en android se almacenan en variables tipo `int`, esto lo puedes ver en el archivo `R.java`.

Incluso puedes realizar un array de sonidos

```
int[] sonido = {R.raw.academiaguarciacivil, R.raw.sonidorodry, R.raw.otrosonido};
```

Comment: Gracias, justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: Excelente Rodry @Rodrypaladin , recuerda que incluso puedes hacer un array para almacenar tus sonidos, por lo tanto este array debe ser de enteros